# Minimongo Use Cases

Tags: meteor, minimongo

In Meteor, minimongo makes it very easy to query the database from within the browser console. But I'm still having trouble understanding why being able to view data in this manner is considered so beneficial. It is nice on occasion to open up the console and be able to see what data is being published and made available to me. What are some other good practical use cases of minimongo? Do you have any examples where minimongo has helped you as a developer?

Comment: if you are familiar with Backbone.js, then Minimongo would be used instead of Backbone.Collections. It is a local data cache that is separated from the representation (DOM tree).

Answer (score 1):

When building an application you can use it to display information to your HTML very easily. Usually you would have logic to connect to your db, ajax it to your front end, then display it & refresh it/update any data.

Here you can make beautiful apps since you're not going to focus on all this boilerplate, you would just be able to call some javascript and read your database as if it were on the client side.

Not only is it faster than calling data from the server every time, updates, deletions and inserts become simple one lines of code to update your back end database. It is extremely convenient. (Not talking about doing it from the JS console)

Being able to view the data in your JS console is merely a side effect of all this. Code that your  app can run also runs from the JS console, not just for Meteor apps, for any web application. While it is quite nice to debug, it's not the intention of it all. The core intention is to make building your app very easy - Since this same code can be used on your front end to display or manipulate data.

You might want to have a look at the [examples that come with Meteor](http://meteor.com/examples) or the [Meteor screencast](https://www.meteor.com/screencast) to understand how it is used. It's very hard to answer how minimongo is used and has been helpful when its nearly ubiquitously used in all Meteor apps.